Mellin transform of the volume form of a probability zonoid and its fundamental strip
Let $ L^n_+$ be the set of all $n$-dimensional nonnegative random vectors $\mathbf X = (X_1, X_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,X_n)^⊤$ with finite and positive marginal expectations, and let $\mathbf Ψ^{(n)}$ be the class of all measurable functions from $\Bbb R^n_+$ to $[0, 1].$ Then $\zeta(\mathbf X)$ of the random vector $\mathbf X$ with joint CDF $F$ is:
Def.
$$\zeta(\mathbf X):=\bigg\{\bigg(\int \psi(\mathbf x)dF(\mathbf x), \int \frac{x_1\psi(\mathbf x)}{E(X_1)}dF(\mathbf x),\cdot\cdot\cdot,\int \frac{x_n\psi(\mathbf x)}{E(X_n)}dF(\mathbf x):\psi \in \mathbf Ψ^{(n)}\bigg)\bigg\}, $$
$$ =\bigg\{\bigg(E\psi(\mathbf X), \frac{E(X_1\psi(\mathbf X))}{E(X_1)},\cdot\cdot\cdot,\frac{E(X_n\psi(\mathbf X))}{E(X_n)}:\psi \in \mathbf Ψ^{(n)}\bigg)\bigg\}. $$
The volume is given by:
$$\mathrm{Vol}(\zeta(\mathbf X))= \frac{1}{(n+1)!}E\big(|\det(Q)|\big) $$
where $Q$ is a $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix whose $i$th row is $(1, \mathbf{ \bar X}^{(i)}),$ $i=1,2,\cdot\cdot\cdot , n+1.$
Here I'll use a normalized version of $\mathbf X$ denoted by $\mathbf{\bar X}$ such that $\bar X_i= X_i/E(X_i),$ $i=1,2,\cdot\cdot\cdot, n.$ Consider $n+1$ $\mathrm{iid}$ $n$-dim. random vectors $\mathbf{ \bar X}^{(1)},\cdot\cdot\cdot, \mathbf{ \bar X}^{(n+1)} $ each with the same distribution as $\mathbf{\bar X}.$
Then the Mellin transform of the volume form is given by the multidimensional Mellin transform:
$$\Pi_n(s_1 \cdot\cdot\cdot s_n)=\int_{\zeta} x_1^{s_1} \cdot\cdot\cdot x_n^{s_n} ~\mathrm{Vol}(\zeta(\mathbf X)) \frac{dx_1\cdot\cdot\cdot dx_n}{x_1\cdot\cdot\cdot x_n}.$$
Assume $\zeta$ is specified by the distribution:
$$ f_t(x_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_n)=C(t)\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\frac{t}{\log x_i}}$$
on $x_i \in(0,1)$, parameter $t>0$, and normalization factor $C(t)$. It can be seen that $f$ is Schwartz as is $\zeta$.

Is there a closed form for $\Pi_2(s_1,s_2)$ and what is its fundamental strip?

